# 2D materials with isotropic Dirac cones

Tags: material-science, graphene, tight-binding

The celebrated material graphene has electrons which can be described by the simple 2D Hamiltonian $H = v_F \left( \sigma_x p_x + \sigma_y p_y \right)$, where $v_F$ is a Fermi velocity.

Silicene, germanene and stanene are less well described by this Hamiltonian due to spin-orbit coupling which opens a gap.

What other materials have bandstructures that can conceivably be described by this gapless Hamiltonian at some point?

Comment: The 2d electron gas on the surface of a 3d topological insulator. While the bulk is insulating there are (semi-)metallic, gapless states on the surface.